# Distance based query advice

Tags: php

Ok its been a while since iv had to do something of this complexity and I'm a little bit stumped.

I have a library class that takes in a postcode and returns an associative array of postcodes in a radius of the entered postcode with the postcode as the key and distance from the original postcode as the value.

example : FK27DJ => 0.094146570284875

The web application is a takeaway restaurant finder and I need to run a query that will find the closest takeaways of each type to the the entered postcode.

There are 4 types of takeaway based on a takeaway_type_id field. So if the user enters their own postcode a single takeaway of each type will be presented to them which is also the closest takeaway of that type to the entered postcode.

So I will need to pass in the array of postcodes from the library class and search the takeaways table for the closest takeaways of each type.

Does this make sense?

The takeaways table contains the following relevant fields:

id(int), takeaway_type_id(int), postcode

Could this be done in a single query? The site is php based.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As that looks like a UK postcode, you need another table that maps postcodes to GPS coordinates (longitude and latitude). You can get that from here. http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2008/07/24/full-uk-postcode-database-for-free/  (other places may also have it, check out http://www.freepostcodes.org.uk/)

Then you need to do a "select" in SQL, joining the two tables, calculating distance which you can do in SQL. "SQRT(POWER(Long1 - long2,2) + POWER(Lat1 - Lat2,2))" will give you the approx distance. WARNING: As this needs to be calculated for each row, restrict the possible results to Long+-range, Lat+-range.

To get an accurate distance, you do need a bit of trig. Here's a function I used in a recent app that does similar, you should be able to massage it to work or even build int othe SQL query.

```
function CalculateDistance($Longitude1, $Latitude1, $Longitude2, $Latitude2) {
    // Not perfect for curvature of earth on the diaganol, but it's close enough ;)
    $LatDiff = abs($Latitude1 - $Latitude2);
    $LongDiff = abs($Longitude1 - $Longitude2);
    // Convert to meters - 1 deg latitude = 111.12km
    $mLatDiff = $LatDiff * 0.11112;
    $mLongDiff = $LongDiff * 0.11112 * cos(($Latitude1 + $Latitude2) / 2);
    // Work out difference.
    $Diff = sqrt( ($mLatDiff * $mLatDiff) + ($mLongDiff * $mLongDiff) );
    return $Diff;
}
```

---

Edit: Adding code sample

Untested code, but edited from a recent project. Will need syntax checking and tweaking, but will give the idea.

```
$UserPostcode = "AB1 2FG";

// Find the Long/Lat of the user (you don;t have to do this, but it saves a lot of DB stress)
// Postcodes is the table that links users to postcodes
$sql = 'SELECT long, lat FROM postcodes WHERE postcode="' . mysql_real_escape_string($UserPostcode) .'"';
// ... Missing a few lines of check row exists, error reporting etc
$UserLat = $row['lat'];
$UserLong = $row['long'];

// Next, come up with an acceptable range so as not to over-stress the DB:
// What are the acceptable limits?
// 1 deg latitude = 111.12km
// LATITUDE: 1km = 1/111.2 degrees of latitude = 0.0089992800575953923686105111591073
// LONGITUDE: 1km = 1/(111.2 * cos(LATITUDE))

$RangeLat = 8 * 1/111.2; // For 8km = 5 miles. Work out what you want here, the larger = more DB stress
$RangeLong = 8 * 1/(111.2 * cos(deg2rad($UserLat)); // For 8km = 5 miles. Work out what you want here, the larger = more DB stress

// Now the query you want.
// You'll need to change this to get restauants by group, but this gives you the essence of what you need:

$sql = 'SELECT r.restaurant_id, r.OtherDetails, r.postcode,
                  p.lat, p.long,
                  SQRT(POWER(p.lat-'.$UserLat.',2) + POWER(p.long-'.$UserLong.',2)) AS distance 
           FROM resturants r
             LEFT JOIN postcodes p ON r.postcode=p.postcode
           WHERE p.lat >='.($UserLat - $RangeLat).' AND p.lat <='.($UserLat + $RangeLat).' AND p.long>='.($UserLong-$RangeLong).' AND p.long>='.($UserLong+$RangeLong).'
           ORDER BY SQRT(POWER(p.lat-'.$UserLat.',2) + POWER(p.long-'.$UserLong.',2)) ASC';
if (!$result = mysql_query($sql)) { ExitError(4, $sql . '<br />' . mysql_error()); }
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // This is where you can count the 4 in each category, and disregard if you get more that 4.
        // If you get less than 4, offer to expand the range - or stick in a loop and do it automatically.

        // Also for efficienty, I'd suggest you remove the "distance" calculation from the SQL and use the function above
        // The function above it more accurate as it users cosine. Then simply sort by distance here instead on in SQL.

        // Also note the above function is written for the northern hemisphere. Also won't work across the date line ;)
        // But that shouldn't be a worry.

}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

But - can it be done in one query: Sure, if you want to bring down the SQL server

Again, not tested, but will give you the gist of what to do. I strongly recommend against it, though!

```
$sql = 'SELECT r.restaurant_id, r.OtherDetails, r.postcode,
                  p.lat, p.long,
                  SQRT(POWER(p.lat-p2.lat,2) + POWER(p.long-p2.long,2)) AS distance 
           FROM resturants r
             LEFT JOIN postcodes p ON r.postcode=p.postcode
             LEFT JOIN postcodes p2 ON p2.postcode="' . mysql_real_escape_string($UserPostcode) .'"
           ORDER BY SQRT(POWER(p.lat-p2.lat,2) + POWER(p.long-p2.long,2)) ASC';
```

// If you go that route, and you want uber-accuracy, I'll let you work out how to get COS in there :). The mySQL functions you need are RADIANS() and COS()

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding the question the class receives a user provided postcode - eg "KY12 3RT" - searches the database for postcodes within a certain radius, returning items from the database along with a calculated 'distance from provided postcode' in a single array. The postcodes table itself contains the longitude and latitude of each postcode already

Comment: I need to search the takeaways table based on the postcodes in the array from the class and return the 4 single nearest takeaways of each type.

Comment: Based on your comment, I've completely understood the question... it'll do exactly what you ask. Unless you also want me to write the code?

Comment: My postcode table already has long and lat fields so why would I need two tables? I am just not understanding how to apply what you are saying to my probelm

Comment: I'll write the code shortly and updater the answer. You're already done the hard buy then!

Comment: OK - code sample added - was answering on the phone earlier, and writing code on the phone is a pain!